# How can I avoid losing precision with ftFmtBcd?

Tags: delphi, precision, delphi-10-seattle, tclientdataset, bcd

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.DB.TFMTBCDField) says:

> TFMTBCDField encapsulates the fundamental behavior common to binary-coded decimal (BCD) fields. BCD values provide greater precision and accuracy than floating-point numbers. BCD fields are often used for storing and manipulating monetary values.

Unfortunately, I'm finding that using such a field in combination with an `Extended` value, I'm losing precision (in this example two digits): if I use

```
BcdField.AsExtended := Value;
```

the value gets actually truncated to four digits. What can I do about this?

*Complete example:*

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LValue: Double;
  LDataset: TClientDataSet;
  LFieldDef: TFieldDef;
begin
  LValue := 1 / 3;
  LDataset := TClientDataSet.Create(self);
  try
    LFieldDef := LDataset.FieldDefs.AddFieldDef;
    LFieldDef.DataType := ftFMTBcd;
    LFieldDef.Size := 6;
    LFieldDef.Precision := 10;
    LFieldDef.Name := 'A';
    LDataset.CreateDataset;
    LDataset.Append;
    LDataset.FieldByName('A').AsExtended := LValue;
    LDataset.Post;
    ShowMessage(FloatToStr(LDataset.FieldByName('A').AsExtended));
    ShowMessage(FloatToStr(LValue));
  finally
    FreeAndNil(LDataset);
  end;
end;
```

*Output (in message boxes):*

```
0,3333
0,333333333333333
```

Comment: Ehm, define it as `ftExtended`?

Comment: Okay, but most of the time we are using `MSSQL` and `NUMERIC(..)` fields, which results in `ftFmtBcd` fields on the delphi side. I don't want to change the fields in the database...

Comment: It seems to be a Seattle problem. Just tried it in Tokyo and was surprised that it worked. Perhaps related to https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16200?

Comment: Try with `LFieldDef.Size := 15; LFieldDef.Precision := 15;`.

Comment: Strictly speaking it would be more accurate to use `TField.AsBCD` which returns a [TBcd](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.FmtBcd.TBcd) record. But there may be a problem... I don't have a recent version to check the source code, but current documentation states that: `TFMTBCDField.Value` is the same as `AsBCD`, which in turn "returns the value of AsCurrency converted to a TBcd value". This implies a bug in that by going via `Currency`, a field specifically intended to support larger precision than `TBCD` is being hamstrung to `Currency` precision in any case.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Doesn't change a thing

Comment: @CraigYoung Thank you. this works! `AsBcd` is overwritten in `TFmtBcdField`, so the documentation for `TField isn't applicable here.

Comment: @ventiseis: it does for me, D10 Tokyo.

Comment: @ventiseis Thanks for confirming. I've written up an answer based on your feedback. You may already be familiar with some of the points raised in my answer; I've included them for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking it would be more accurate to use [`TField.AsBCD`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.DB.TField.AsBCD) which returns a [`TBcd`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.FmtBcd.TBcd) record. `TFmtBcdField` overrides the default implementation and returns an *accurate* `TBcd` record.

`TBcd` is a record structure with support for simple arithmetic operators and implicit conversion from `Integer` and `Double`. So it should be suitable for most purposes.

The drawbacks are:

- Mathematical operations may be marginally slower due to lack of built in machine instruction. But it's probably a reasonable trade-off for cases where precise representation is required. *Benchmark and evaluate as needed.*
- Some functions that take `Double` or `Integer` parameters may need `TBcd` overload implementations.

---

Some related considerations:

- The use of `Double` is not appropriate if you require accurate precision due to the nature floating point representation. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for more info.
- The use of `Extended` has the same problems as `Double` even though the extra 2 bytes provide greater range and higher precision - *it's still a floating point data type*. Furthermore, `Extended` has its own problems. Take note of the warnings [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Extended).
- If you don't need precise representation, then you can convert to `Double` using `BcdToDouble`. See [BCD Support Routines](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/BCD_Support_Routines).
- Another option to consider in cases where you don't need more than 4 decimals, but do need precise representation: Use the [`Currency`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Currency) data type. It's represented as a 64-bit integer with assumed division by 10000 which is how it supports 4 decimal digits.